# why the return id was usize when inserting record

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

I am using rust `rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)` diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres","64-column-tables","chrono","serde_json"] }` to insert a record into PostgreSQL 13 database, what I am trying to do is that fetch the inserted record id after the insert action. This is part of the rust code looks like right now:

```
let menu_id = diesel::insert_into(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::menu_resource::table)
        .values(&new_menu_resource)
        .returning(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::menu_resource::id)
        .on_conflict_do_nothing()
        .execute(&connection)
        .unwrap();
```

this is my `menu_resource` define in rust:

```
table! {
    menu_resource (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        name -> Varchar,
        res_type -> Int4,
        created_time -> Int8,
        updated_time -> Int8,
        remark -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        path -> Varchar,
        parent_id -> Int4,
        component -> Nullable<Varchar>,
        sort -> Int4,
        name_zh -> Varchar,
        tree_id_path -> Varchar,
        code -> Varchar,
    }
}
```

but the recevied `menu_id` was `usize` data type. why return the `unsize` data type not the `i32`? what I am missing? what should I do to make it return the id with `i32`? I am follow the docs from here: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.insert_into.html that tell that could returnt he value like this:

```
let inserted_names = diesel::insert_into(users)
    .values(&vec![
        name.eq("Diva Plavalaguna"),
        name.eq("Father Vito Cornelius"),
    ])
    .returning(name)
    .get_results(&connection);
assert_eq!(Ok(vec!["Diva Plavalaguna".to_string(), "Father Vito Cornelius".to_string()]), inserted_names);
```

Comment: The `menu_id` variable name is misleading, since what `execute` returns is not an ID at all. Better rename or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation of `RunQueryDsl::execute`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/query_dsl/trait.RunQueryDsl.html#method.execute) indicates that the return value is the number of rows affected,
which is naturally represented by using an unsigned type `usize`.
If you really want `i32` instead, cast the return value by yourself.

Comment: from the docs that could return the inserted value: https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.insert_into.html @kotatsuyaki

Comment: If you want to get the inserted *values* instead of the *number of rows affected*, you have to use `returning` and `get_results` instead of `execute` to do the job.